# Flickering issue with UICollectionView while reloading

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I'm developing an application where the user clicks on a menu item and the tableView should scroll according to the selected item.

But the problem is  collectionView flicks a little bit while reloading.

Here I'm  getting the visible section.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
if let firstVisibleIndexPath = self.tblRestaurantFeed.indexPathsForVisibleRows?[0]{
    self.tableViewVisibleSection = firstVisibleIndexPath.section
}}
```

When the variable is updating the I'm reloading the collectionview  and using scroll to item

```
var tableViewVisibleSection:Int = 0{
didSet{
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, animations: {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        })
        let visibleIndexPaths = collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems
        let itemIndex = IndexPath(item: self.selectedTag, section: 0)
        if(!visibleIndexPaths.contains(itemIndex)){
            UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
                self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: self.selectedTag, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
            }
        }
}}
```

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: is that blue part indicates Section? @Ranjan

Comment: The top grey colour background is collection view with blue colour selected item, and where the "Description" is showing this is the section header of tableview

Comment: did you check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65833528/4061501)?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are calling **.reloadData()** from an animation block. Please try the code below and let me know if it works.

```
var tableViewVisibleSection: Int = 0 {
didSet {
        let visibleIndexPaths = collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems
        let itemIndex = IndexPath(item: self.selectedTag, section: 0)
        if(!visibleIndexPaths.contains(itemIndex)){
                self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: self.selectedTag, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
        }
}}
```

Comment: Facing same issue after removed the animation block.

Comment: @RanjankumarSahu Try using didSelectItemAtIndexPath instead of willDisplay cell.

Comment: @RanjankumarSahu try now without the **.reloadData()** call. Using the updated code.

Comment: How to select the collection view item .

here is the cellForItemAt indexPath:  code 


     
  `btnTag.isSelected = (indexPath.row == self.selectedTag)
            btnTag.layer.cornerRadius = btnTag.frame.height / 2
            btnTag.backgroundColor =  btnTag.isSelected ? .blue : .clear`

Answer (score 0):

Try below one.

```
var currentMenu: Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
        ...
        
        collectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(item: currentMenu, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: [])
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        currentMenu = indexPath.row
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: currentMenu), at: .top, animated: true)
        collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.first, abs(indexPath.section - currentMenu) == 1, scrollView.isDragging else { return }
        currentMenu = indexPath.section
        collectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(item: currentMenu, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
    }
}
```